# Jquery dynamically moving a Div and getting its position relative to it's parent

Tags: javascript

I have a script that requires the user to be able to position a div on top of a selected image. I have done thaty part but I am stuck on how to get the position of the movable div relative to its parent div.

My current JavaScript:

```
window.onload = addListeners();
var x_pos = 0,
y_pos = 0;

function addListeners() {
   document.getElementById('ClientNametext').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
   window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    var div = document.getElementById('ClientNametext');
    x_pos = e.clientX - div.offsetLeft;
    y_pos = e.clientY - div.offsetTop;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e) {
    var div = document.getElementById('ClientNametext');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = (e.clientY - y_pos) + 'px';
    div.style.left = (e.clientX - x_pos) + 'px';
   console.log(div.style.top);
   console.log(div.style.left);
}
```

Is there a way of tracking and capturing the movable div position and storing the result in a variable I can use with a PHP insert query.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Consider including a minimal HTML snippet alongside your JS so that we can debug a bit easier.

Comment: @Santi I have added some additional code to try and write the output div.style.top = (e.clientY - y_pos) + 'px';
div.style.left = (e.clientX - x_pos) + 'px'; But I do not see any data when debugging. What do you mean when you say "Consider including a minimal HTML snippet alongside your JS". Many thankd for your time.

Comment: Obviously there is HTML that goes along with this code, right? All the divs that you're selecting and moving around, etc? As it stands right now your question is just a bunch of javascript, but we have no idea what your page looks like or anything. If you include a small bit of HTML in your question that allows us to actually *run* your code, you're much more likely to get answers. As a side-note, jQuery is not the same as JavaScript. You mentioned jQuery and tagged jQuery, but this question has no jQuery in it whatsoever. I've edited to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and added a new function `updatePos`, it is invoked on page load and mousemove.

```js
var posX = 0,
    posY = 0;

function updatePos() {
    var div = document.getElementById('ClientNametext');
    var parentPos = div.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var childPos = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsets = {
        top: childPos.top - parentPos.top,
        left: childPos.left - parentPos.left
    }
    posY = offsets.top;
    posX = offsets.left;
    document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = "(" + posX + ", " + posY + ")";
}
 
updatePos();


function divMove(e) {
    var div = document.getElementById('ClientNametext');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = (e.clientY - y_pos) + 'px';
    div.style.left = (e.clientX - x_pos) + 'px';
  
    updatePos(); //added this line
}

//your code:

window.onload = addListeners();
var x_pos = 0,
y_pos = 0;

function addListeners() {
   document.getElementById('ClientNametext').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
   window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    var div = document.getElementById('ClientNametext');
    x_pos = e.clientX - div.offsetLeft;
    y_pos = e.clientY - div.offsetTop;
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}
```

```css
#ClientNametext {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
#offset {
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  left:90px;
  top:80px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="pos"></div>
<div id="offset">
  <div id="ClientNametext">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for looking at and producing the function. I will work with it and get back once I have it working.

Comment: Is there a way of making the <div id="ClientNametext">&nbsp;</div> relative to its parent div. At the moment I have the following: <div id="preview4">
<div id="ClientNametext"></div>
</div> so that the coordinates are with in <div id="preview4">, does that make sence?

Comment: I updated the code, it is now relative to the parent.

Comment: so sorry to be a pain in the neck, but when I try and move the div it moves to PosY 0 PosX 0 i.e top left, of the complete page rather than staying within the parent div, can you prevent this?